# problems with boundaries in $\mathbb{R^ 2}$

Tags: general-topology

problems with boundaries in $\mathbb{R^ 2}$.

Hello there, i am following a course of topology and need to determine the boundaries and interiors of the following sets.

$A =\{x \times y | y=0\}$

$B =\{x \times y | x>0, y \neq 0\}$

$C = A \cup B$

$D = \{x \times y | x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$

$E = \{x \times y | 0 < x^2 - y^ 2 \leq 1\}$

$F = \{x \times y | x \neq 0, y\leq \frac{1}{x}\}$

I don't seem to understand quite yet how this works, the first three are pretty easy. But when writing out the other ones i don't have the right answers. Is there a certain trick to these kind of questions, or is drawing the only thing that works?

Kees

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{int}A=\varnothing$ and $\bar A=A$ therefore $\operatorname{bound}A=A$

$\operatorname{int}B=B$ and $\bar B={x\geq 0}$ therefore $\operatorname{bound}B=\{x,x=0\}\cup \{y=0, x\geq 0\}$

$\operatorname{int}D=\varnothing$ and $\bar D=\mathbb{R}^2$ therefore $\operatorname{bound}D=\mathbb{R}^2$

$\operatorname{int}E = \{x \times y | 0 \lt x^2 - y^ 2 \lt 1\}$ and $\bar E= \{x \times y | 0 \leq x^2 - y^ 2 \leq 1\}$ therefore $$\operatorname{bound}E= \{x \times y | 0 = x^2 - y^ 2 \lor x^2-y^2=1\}$$

$\operatorname{int}F = \{x \times y | x\neq 0\land y\lt 1/x\}$ and $\bar F= \{x \times y | y\leq 1/x\}$ therefore $\operatorname{bound}F= \{x \times y | x=0\lor y=1/x\}$

Comment: thanks for your help, i actually have the most problems with the last 3. Do you understand those?

Comment: Yes I am in a dinner now can it wait

Comment: of course :), i have all the time of the world